# Fatal error: Column not found: Unknown column 'Attribute_Code' (Magento)

Tags: magento, attributes, filtering

I have a custom module that request the collection of products grouped by an attribute code but on activate anchor on that category i got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'myattribute' in 'group statement'
```

My method is:

```
protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        if ($this->isEnabled()) {
            if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
                echo $this->getSelect()->columns(array('e.myattribute_ids' => new Zend_Db_Expr("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.color SEPARATOR ',')")))->group('myattribute');

            }

            $this->getSelect()->columns(array('e.myattribute_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')));
        }
        return parent::_beforeLoad();
    }
```

What im doing wrong?

The module explanation is here:

http://goo.gl/2bUqXs

Answer (score 0):

please check the attibute "myattribute" is  added properly

Comment: It is, as i say, on activate the Anchor on Category list option i got the error message that the column "myattribute" is not there.

Comment: please enable that attribute in  "Used in Product Listing" from Manage Attribute...

Comment: Used in Product Listing Is se to Yes.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.